# Rails get second record joins table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables `Promo` and `Image`

`Promo` has  id and name

`Image` has promo_id name and img_url

assosiations => promo has_many images

and i want to fetch second record from `image` table  where promo_id 1,

for_example if i do `Promo.first.images.second` it's bad for perfomace
if my image table has a lot records

so i guess i need something like `Promo.joins(:images).where('????')`

Answer (score 0):

> i want to fetch second record from image table where promo_id 1

Since you have `promo_id` in `images` table, no `join` is needed:

```ruby
Image.where(promo_id: 1).second
#=> SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."promo_id" = $1 ORDER BY "images"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["promo_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
```

If you would like to also specify the image `id`, just add it to `where`:

```ruby
Image.where(promo_id: 1, id: 2)
#=> SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."promo_id" = $1 AND "images"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["promo_id", 1], ["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

This assumes that the second image `id` is `2`.

Both options will generate one simple query to your database, so you shouldn't have performance issues (i also assume that you have set indexes in your `images` table).